# How to design a user reputation table

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am busy scoping out an application and one of the requirement is user feedback for services rendered.

I was thinking of creating a reputation system for this: using up votes and down votes for a given service.

Having never created something like this, I am looking for help with the database design:

**User Story:**
Service provider provides a painting service to Customer. On completion of the work, each has an opportunity to rate each other. The rating will contribute towards further work for the service provider as well as further workers for the client.

Table structure:

**User:**

```
{
    "User Id": 1,
    "Name": "Service Provider"
  },{
    "User Id": 2,
    "Name": "Customer"
  },
```

**Reputation:**

```
{
    "Reputation Id": 1,
    "user_rating":1,  //i.e. doing the rating
    "user_rated":2,   //i.e. being rated
    "Rating": 1,
    "Service Identity": 123
    "Comment": "Nice customer to work for..."
  },
{
    "Reputation Id": 2,
    "user_rating":2,
    "user_rated":1,
    "Rating": 1,
    "Service Identity": 123
    "Comment": "Great Service Received..."
  },
```

**Service**

```
  {
        "Service Id": 123,
        "Description": "Paint the house..."
      },
```

How could this be made more extensive or more useful?

Is the design too simple or should it be more extensive?

I don't want people abusing the system, perhaps a specific reputation is required before a user can vote or leave comments etc.

Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated!